# Numerical Integration - combine LevinRule with DuffyCoordinates?

Tags: numerical-integration, numerics

For multidimensional numerical integration (9+ dimensions), with an oscillatory function, is there a way to combine two methods like DuffyCoordinates and LevinRule in NIntegrate[]?

Edited: For the integrand, see for example
[Numerical Integration - possible methods to complete execution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/169478/numerical-integration-possible-methods-to-complete-execution?noredirect=1#comment445600_169478)

Comment: Interesting question. Can you post your integrand.

Comment: Just provided an integrand - link.